# convert raw audio to mp3(wav) with adpcm_ima_wav codec

Tags: ffmpeg, codec

I want to convert raw audio(binary) to audio file(mp3, wav etc) with same audio info as originals'.

Here's video(mp4) file that has audio stream's, and following is the audio stream info pulled out from ffmpeg.

> Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: adpcm_ima_wav (ms[0][17] / 0x1100736D), 32000 Hz, 2 channels, s16p, 256 kb/s (default)

I used,

> ffmpeg.exe -f s16le -ar 32000 -ac 1 -i raw_audio.raw -acodec copy output.wav

Seems converting process is finished okay, but the problem is, if I listen the output.wav, there's the big noise from output wav file. Also, it's not the same audio from original video.
I tried specifying "adpcm_ima_wav" codec with "-f" switch, but it doesn't work.

Any suggenstion please?

- by the way I know how to extract audio from video with ffmpeg, I just want to convert RAW audio binary data to .WAV or .MP3
  (ffmpeg.exe -f test.mp4 -map 0:a:0 audio.mp3)

Comment: Anybody knows how to use FFMPEG, "ffmpeg.exe -f adpcm_ima_wav ~ " this way?